# embed pdf from blob to html/php page

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, embed, blob

I'm storing PDF documents in a database as a LONGBLOB. Is there a solution to embed these PDFs into a webpage? I found JavaScript's PDFObject, but it only works with PDF files stored in a folder. Alternatively, can I convert a PDF from the blob long enough to read it?

Currently, I open PDFs with the following script:

```
require_once 'init.php';

$sql = "SELECT data FROM dms_files WHERE id=42";

// the result of the query
$result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());

// set the header for the image
header( "Pragma: private");
header( "Cache-Control: max-age=0");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

echo $pdf;
```

It opens PDF as a file, but it doesn't embed it into the page.

Uploading PDFs:

```
$docData = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['document']['tmp_name']));
$docProperties = filesize($_FILES['document']['tmp_name']);
$sqldoc = "INSERT INTO dms_files(mime ,data) VALUES('{$docProperties}', '{$docData}')";
$current_id = mysql_query($sqldoc) or die("<b>Error:</b> Problem on Doc. Insert<br/>" . mysql_error());
$docId = mysql_insert_id();
```

I tried to use this:

```
<?php
require_once 'init.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM dms_files WHERE id = 42 ";

// the result of the query
$result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

$basedir = 'LIB/';
$pdfname = strtolower(preg_replace('/([^\w\d\-_]+)/', '-', $row->nazov_rd));
$filename = $basedir . $pdfname . '_' . $row->id. '.pdf';
$file_content = base64_decode($row->data);
file_put_contents('filename.pdf', $row->data);

?>
```

However, it showed the following errors:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/D/PDFSHOW/pdfshow.php on line 11
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/D/PDFSHOW/pdfshow.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/D/PDFSHOW/pdfshow.php on line 13
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/D/PDFSHOW/pdfshow.php on line 14

What is wrong? When I open filename.pdf, the preview says that "the file could not be opened because it's empty"

---

I was able to solve it; this was missing:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
```

Comment: Can you post the complete code you use now?

Comment: @Bram look at first post I added the upload part

Answer (score 0):

Create a different page in which you embed this element using the javascript pdfobject.

Comment: I thinking about this in relation to the iframe but. I dont know how generate link for pdf stored in blob... any idea ?

Comment: ulink all pdf on tempdir(if exist)..read the blob from DB...and download it to a temp dir...load-embed the created pdf...

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me in Laravel 5.7 step an arrangement taking from the database**

```
 foreach ($documento as $obj) 
  { 
    // $file = substr($obj->Nombre,0,strlen($obj->Nombre)-3).'pdf';
    $filenombre = $Nombre.'.pdf';

    $bytes = base64_decode($obj->file);

    //header('Content-type: "'.$tipo.'"; charset=utf-8');
    header("Content-type: application/pdf"); 
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filenombre));    
    //header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filenombre));   
    print $bytes; 
    //header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filenombre));   
    //readfile($filenombre);    
    exit(0); 

  }
```